# Why is my float mirroring another float instead of having its own value?

Tags: c#, reference, floating-point

I'm not sure if the question was clear enough so I'll show the code and what's actually going on. Exerpts of the code's relevant parts are as follows:

```
public class MyClass : BaseClass
{
   public override void UpdateValue() // This is the base class' abstract method.
   {
      MyObject obj = GetObject();
      OriginalValue = obj.Value;
      obj.SetValue(this.Value);  // I know "this." is not needed here. It's just for this exerpt's readability.
   }

   public float OriginalValue { private set; get; }

   public float Value
   {
      set
      {
         this.value = value;
         {...}
      }
      get => value;
   }

   public MyObject GetObject() => {...}

   private float value;
}

public class MyObject
{
   public float Value
   {
      set
      {
         if {...}
         else SetValue(value);
      }
      get => value;
   }

   internal void SetValue(float value) => this.value = value;

   private float value;
}
```

As you can see, my intention is to keep `MyObject`'s Original Value whenever `MyClass.UpdateValue()` is called so that I may restore it later on. However, what happens is that `MyClass.OriginalValue` will always have the same value as `MyObject.Value`.

Say for example that `MyObject.Value` is currently 10 and `MyClass.Value` is 15. That means that once `MyClass.UpdateValue()` is called, `MyClass.OriginalValue` should be 10 and `MyObject.Value` should be 15. Instead of that, `MyClass.OriginalValue` will also be 15. That will still happen even if I add another `obj.SetValue(x)` in the method, making `OriginalValue` be `x` instead of the object's original value.

So, my question is: is `MyClass.OriginalValue` really mirroring `MyObject.Value`? If not, what is going on? And how can I fix this issue?

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: When you call `MyClass.Update()` you assign to `OriginalValue` the value from inner `MyObject`. Why? I think you should remove this assignment. You can also make whole property `OriginalValue` immutable by removing the setter if you intend to keep it as a backup. Assign the value only once in class constructor.

Comment: That's troublesome. I cannot do that because `Update()` is called with certain frequency and therefore `OriginalValue` should change accordingly, meaning that creating a new `MyClass` every time it is called wouldn't be wise. However, I could make a `private readonly struct` with just a `float` inside to behave as `OriginalValue`, even though it'd use up more memory than what I had hoped. Is there another way of making `OriginalValue` not get its value from inner `MyObject`? Thanks for the suggestion, by the way.

Comment: _"`Update()` is called with certain frequency"_ - can you give more details about it? _"it'd use up more memory"_ - why memory consumption of additional `float` field concerns you? Are you creating millions or these objects or maybe the platform your code is running on is memory limited? It sounds like you are only showing us pieces of a much bigger picture. Please, update the question and share more details about the context of your problem, so a broader range of solutions can be offered.

Comment: Yes, there's much more than that. I've posted only the most relevant pieces of the code. The entirety of it is quite extensive and I fear it would reveal too much of my work. Regarding your quotes, `Update()` would be called irregularly, depending on the users themselves, but nothing like "millions of calls" or anything like that. At most, a few calls in a minute. Regarding memory consumption, I'm confident that I'm very very far from the limit, but I always prefer to take the most efficient approach whenever possible. It's just for the sake of efficiency, nothing too concerning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing weird is going on with the posted code...

The easiest explanation is probably that `UpdateValue()` is being called after `MyObject`'s `Value` is set.

I suggest you try setting some breakpoints in `UpdateValue()` and `MyObject.Value` to see which one is called last...

Comment: I could do that, true, but I wonder why it would do that, since `OriginalValue` is, as per in the code, set **prior** to the other object's `Value` change. I find it awkward why it would ever just set `OriginalValue` **after** the object's `Value` is set.

Comment: Well, your breakpoint suggestion did bear fruit. Through it, I learned that the method was being called TWICE, henceforth `OriginalValue`'s incorrect value. Needless to say that I'm terribly embarrassed. Anyhow, I appreciate you for showing me how dumb it was not to properly test it beforehand.